# How can I install Windows without uninstalling existing Linux?

Tags: operating-systems, multi-boot, windows-installer

I installed Lubuntu 12.10 on a single drive. How can I install XP without uninstalling Lubuntu 12.10?

Comment: You need to share more info about your current installation. Do you run two OS side by side by installing them to different partitions? Do you run Ubuntu on Windows or on VM?

Answer (score 2):

Use partition manager software, redistribute HDD space so that there's a partition big enough for Windows, back up MBR, install Windows, run Linux repair manager to restore MBR, wipe out your red eyes and have a beer.

Answer (score 2):

This is not very easy, but it can be done.

Boot off [PartedMagic](http://partedmagic.com) CD or USB stick, use `GParted` to shrink your Linux ext4 partition.

After that, you can install XP into free space.

You may need to reinstall `grub` to make it all bootable.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a dual-boot. The steps are just the same as you are installing an operating system –  but install it in a different hard-disk partition.